# Ordered list formatting with indentation and different list types

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've received a request to do this type of formatting for a Terms and Conditions page but the formatting styles that CSS allows doesn't seem to allow such indentation and combinations of list types.

Is there anyway this type of formatting can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing `ul` elements within each other? That way you can style them individually with css.

Comment: Workaround: You could just use a PDF of the TOC.   It  would bypass your problem. Also it's much easier for users to download the TOC page if they need to.

Comment: @Josh have you ever downloaded a *Terms and conditions*? :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I knew that was coming...

Comment: @Josh Good idea but I wonder how well is opening a PDF document in a browser supported?

Comment: @catandmouse I see your point but all major browsers support it. And if not, it will download and then they can open it.

Answer (score 2):

okay, here's my answer for you:

```html
<ul>
    <li type="1">Lorem</li>
        <ul>1.1 Lorem Ipsum:
            <ol type="i">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a tortor in quam convallis tristique. Etiam aliquam mauris id justo malesuada aliquet. Nullam id libero nec enim fringilla gravida. Fusce pretium neque est, ut fermentum mauris pretium at. Sed tincidunt, nibh tincidunt efficitur iaculis, risus neque vehicula enim, eget convallis elit libero a justo. Mauris id mollis neque. Integer pharetra id risus condimentum mattis. Donec rutrum ante erat, vitae congue nibh vehicula lobortis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc ac vulputate nisi, ut ornare urna. Nunc mattis diam a pellentesque viverra. Duis eu ipsum non nisl ornare congue nec ac lacus. Cras convallis diam nec lacus pharetra, eu tristique diam eleifend. Nam quis vehicula lectus.</li>
                <li>Lorem blablabla</li>
                <ol type="a">
                    <li>Lorem blablabla</li>
                    <li>Lorem blablabla</li>
                </ol>
                <li>Lorem blablabla</li>
            </ol>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

UPDATE: you can change the type for the li, ol so they will match which type you want by this: w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp